# Prove that if $n$ is odd, then $C_n$ is antimagic.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $n$ is odd, then $C_n$, the cyclic graph of $n$ vertices, is [antimagic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntimagicGraph.html).

How would you construct and write the proof for this problem?

Comment: If you label the edges $1,2,...,n$ counterclockwise, the sum of the labels at each vertex is different, isn't it? For all vertices except the last we get an odd sum $a+a+1=2a+1$, which are different for different $a$. At the last vertex we get $n+1$ which is even and therefore different from all the other sums.

Comment: @barkmanos wow.. a little harsh don't you think? At least I'm not mean...

Comment: @MJJ: Sorry, didn't mean to be mean, comment deleted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction is as follows... Building on Nathanson's comment, if we construct a sequence of integers from the sums of adjacent edge labels in a cyclic graph, we get the sequence consisting of every odd number in $[1, 2n-1]$ and one value whose parity is variable (the last value in the sequence).  This last value is $n+1$.  If $n$ is even, $n+1$ is in $\{1, 3, 5, ..., 2n-1\}$, otherwise, $n+1$ is even and can't be in this sequence.